# Scala currying and type inference

Tags: scala

I'm trying to figure out how to use currying in Scala.

In the following snippet:

```
object Foo {

  def foo(a:Int)(b:Int)(c:Int) : Int = a + b + c

  def main(a:Array[String]) {

    val f = foo(1)(2) _ 
    def g : Int => Int = foo(1)(2) 
    // def h = foo(1)(2) 

    println(f(3))
    println(g(3))
    // println(h(3))
  }
}
```

the definitions for `f` and `g` work, the one for `h` does not:

```
/home/vlad/Desktop/b.scala:9: error: missing arguments for method foo in object Main;
follow this method with `_' if you want to treat it as a partially applied function
    def h = foo(1)(2)
```

What's the reasoning behind this being illegal? It seems to me that Scala should be able to figure out that after calling `foo(1)(2)` you'd be left with an `Int => Int`.

Comment: I've always thought that the compiler is not smart enough for this case, another variation that works is `def h = foo(1)(2)(_)` where you inform the compiler that the third parameter will be provided eventually.

Comment: @EndeNeu A lot of languages allow that, I think Haskell among them, so it is not the compiler behaving dull. This is intended, see the link in my answer

Comment: In addition in Scala both partial application and eta-expansion (`_` at the end) are actually converting a method (which can't be partially applied) to a function object. Some conversions are risky when they are used implicitly so they are not allowed. In Haskell there are no conversions, it's always true application.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is intended. If it were allowed (some languages really allow that), that would make it work when you forget to put an argument, and instead of compile-time error you would expect. This happens so often that scala authors decide to trade-off here and disallow this notation.

Martin told about that in his book, see "Why the trailing underscore?" http://www.artima.com/pins1ed/functions-and-closures.html#8.7